# Purpose of GValue, GTypeValueTable, GTypeInfo and GParamSpec

Tags: gtk, gnome, glib, gobject

GObject library is really awfully documented. It's damn hard to figure the purposes of entities created. Namely, I don't get the roles of `GValue`, `GTypeValueTable`, `GTypeInfo`, `GParamSpec` and `TypeData`.

In brief, the process of type registration is as follows. Each type is represented by a `TypeNode` structure. There are 2 storages of `TypeNode` structures: `static_fundamental_type_nodes array` for storing `TypeNodes` of static fundamental types and `static_type_nodes_ht` hash table for static non-fundamental types. Each `GType` is just the memory address of the corresponding `TypeNode` in case of non-fundamental types or index of `TypeNode` in `static_fundamental_type_nodes` in case of fundamental types. What happens to dynamic types - I don't know, please explain me if you can. The corresponding code resides in gtype_init function, responsible for initialization of the type system: http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gtype.c#n4323.

[image]

`GValue`, `GParamSpec` and `GObject` are `GTypes` themselves, so they are registered as types.

`GValue` is meant used to register new type values through it, but how?.

`GParameters` and `GParamSpec` seem to be required for registering `GObject` type (not sure). How exactly it is done? What are the roles of each?

MOST IMPORTANTLY: What are the roles of `GTypeValueTable`, `GTypeInfo` and `TypeData`? `TypeData` is referrenced by `TypeNode` and contains `GTypeValueTable` as well as substructures BoxedData, ClassData, IFaceData, InstanceData (why Instance, aren't we registering type?). Moreover, they seems to duplicate each other, cause ALL of them contain references to base_init/finalize, class_init/finalize has a reference to `GTypeValueTable`.

So, GObject papas, if you're reading this, please, explain yourselves! Describe the purpose  of those structures you use.

Answer (score 18):

The only two of these that you really need to care about unless you're attempting to work on some very low level code are GValue and GParamType

I'll start with `GParamType`

`GParamType` is for used for registering a property with a GObject. Say, for example, I have a GObject subclass called Person, and I wanted it to have two properties: Name and Age. In the `class_init` function I would register these like so

```
{
    GParamSpec *pspec;

    . . .

    pspec = g_param_spec_string ("name", "Name", "The name of the person", "", G_PARAM_READWRITE | G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS);
    g_object_class_install_property (object_class, PROP_NAME, pspec);

    pspec = g_param_spec_int ("age", "Age", "The age of the person", 0, G_PARAM_READWRITE | G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS);
    g_object_class_install_property (object_class, PROP_AGE, spec);

    . . .
}
```

Now you can call `g_object_get` or `g_object_set` on those properties and the system will know how to handle it

```
char *name;
int age;
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (person), "name", "Steve", "age", 37, NULL);
g_object_get (G_OBJECT (person), "name", &name, "age", &age, NULL);

g_print ("%s is %d years old\n", name, age);

// And because the type system knows when a property is a string, it knows how to give
// you a copy of the string, so you need to free it once you've finished with it
g_free (name);
```

The various parameters are explained here: [GParamSpec](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-GParamSpec.html#GParamFlags) There are GValue types for all the standard types: strings, bools, ints etc, and some other libraries such as GStreamer will register their own custom ones.

Outside of installing properties on GObjectClass you very rarely need to deal with GParamSpec. The two main occasions where they appear is in the GObjectClass set/get_property methods and the GObject notify signal. It is useful in the last case to detect which property has received the notify signal, by calling `g_param_spec_get_name`, but really it's better to use a more specific notify signal like so:

```
g_signal_connect (person, "notify::name", G_CALLBACK (name_changed_cb), NULL);
g_signal_connect (person, "notify::age", G_CALLBACK (age_changed_cb), NULL);
```

rather than

```
g_signal_connect (person, "notify", G_CALLBACK (something_changed_cb), NULL);
```

Sometimes you may want to create your own structures and use those for the properties. For example if I had

```
struct _PersonDetails {
    char *name;
    int age;
}
```

and instead of having two properties on the Person object, I wanted one called "details". The GLib type system does not know how to deal with my custom `struct _PersonDetails` so I would need to create a boxed type for it, so that it knew how to correctly copy/free the structure as it is passed around the Glib internals. And that is where `GValue` comes in.

`GValue` is for wrapping values of different types so they can be copied and freed correctly (if they need to be), and so that generic functions can be used.

For example, the GObjectClass method set_property has the prototype of

```
void set_property (GObject *object, guint property_id, const GValue *value, GParamSpec *pspec)
```

This means that any type which can be represented by a GValue can be passed in and specific functions such as set_int_property, set_string_property, set_bool_property are not required.

It also means that the functions `g_object_set` and `g_object_get` know how to deal with the parameters that are passed in because it knows that the property "name" is registered to be a string type, and it has the functions necessary to copy/free that string.

More about GValue can be found here - [Generic values](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Generic-values.html)

To register our custom `struct _PersonDetails` with the GLib type system we would create a custom Boxed type which told the system how to copy and free it. The details are here: [Boxed Types](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html)

```
G_DEFINE_BOXED_TYPE (PersonDetails, person_details,
                     person_details_copy,
                     person_details_free)
. . .

static gpointer
person_details_copy (gpointer data)
{
    struct _PersonDetails *details = (struct _PersonDetails *)data;
    struct _PersonDetails *copy = g_new (struct _PersonDetails, 1);

    // We need to copy the string
    copy->name = g_strdup (details->name);
    copy->age = details->age;

    return (gpointer) copy;
}

static void
person_details_free (gpointer data)
{
    struct _PersonDetails *details = (struct _PersonDetails *)data;

    // name was allocated so it needs freed as well
    g_free (details->name);

    g_free (details);
}
```

Now we can register our type using

```
pspec = g_param_spec_boxed ("details", "Details", "The person's details", person_details_get_type (), G_PARAM_READWRITE | G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS);
g_object_class_install_property (object_class, PROP_DETAILS, pspec);
```

Comment: Best and most explicit explanation regarding this topic I read until now. +1

Comment: the g_param_spec_gtype() call is wrong in this case: for boxed types you should use g_param_spec_boxed(); g_param_spec_gtype() is for properties storing the actual GType value. also, to register a boxed type you should use the G_DEFINE_BOXED_TYPE() macro, which generates the get_type() function for you.

Comment: @ebassi fixed the _spec_boxed call.

Comment: @iain thanks for your answer, it's really helpful and useful for me to understand gobject. And could you please explain how GTypeValueTable works? I'm confused about it. Sometimes it looks like virtual table in C++, but it only value handler function pointers inside.